# Stripe - "the payment method type is invalid" for Setup Intent

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I'm trying to get paid with stripe at my restaurant.

I get an error when I try to use several of the payment methods [Stripe supports for SetupIntent](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/integration-options).

I can use `'card', 'sofort', 'bancontact', 'ideal', 'sepa_debit'` payment methods but when I choose one of the supported:

`'au_becs_debit', 'boleto', 'acss_debit', 'us_bank_account'`

methods I get the following error.

```php
Stripe\Exception\InvalidRequestException
The payment method type "us_bank_account" is invalid. See https://stripe.com/docs/api/setup_intents/create#create_setup_intent-payment_method_types for the full list of supported payment method types.
https://yemeksofort.com/cart-checkout
```

```php
$user = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user();
$stripeCustomer = $user->createOrGetStripeCustomer();

$params = [
    'payment_method_types' => [
        'card', 'sofort', 'bancontact', 'ideal', 'sepa_debit'
    ],
    'customer' => $stripeCustomer->id,
];

$stripeIntent = $user->createSetupIntent($params);
```

I thought there was a restriction on my Stripe account but I have allowed all payment methods. Above is my PHP code. Does anyone have a solution or guide? Thank you.

Comment: Is the method `us_bank_account` available for the country you've registered your Stripe account in? From the site I see it's in Turkey so I don't know if that affects availability of methods. I base my comment on this: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/overview#bank-debits

Comment: @MihailMinkov Thank you for your recommendation. Considering the finding, I tried payment methods such as EPS valid in Europe. But they have the same problem.

Comment: I'd recommend you contact Stripe support, because this I think is more a bank related issue rather than a technical one, but not 100% sure.

Comment: @MihailMinkov Thank you, I will contact support and add the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I contacted Stripe support.

The error message the API returns is incorrect. My account location is Belgium and I needed a US Stripe account to use these methods.

They conveyed that it is not possible to change the Stripe account location.
Thanks to everyone who helped.